# Ant - Setting ClassPath Does Not Work For Batch Test

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have this and works fine:

```
<target name="runjunit">
    <junit>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${build}"/>
            <fileset dir="lib">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath> 
        <test name="com.xyzcompany.abcproject.test.junit.CalculatorTest"/>
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

However, I have multiple tests. So I do this:

```
<target name="runjunit">
    <junit>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${build}"/> <---- this doesn't seem to work anymore
            <fileset dir="lib">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath> 
        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="com/xyzcompany/abcproject/test/junit">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

However, that tells me the directory doesn't exist:

`C:\Users\me\Desktop\repository\mainproj\trunk\com\xyzcompany\abcproject\test\junit does not exist.`

The above should be:

`C:\Users\me\Desktop\repository\mainproj\trunk\build\com\xyzcompany\abcproject\test\junit`

As you see, the pathelement in classpath would set trunk/build/com in the single test, but doesn't in batchtest.

Directory and package names obfuscated for privacy.

Any idea how I can change the batchtest so pathelement in classpath actually works? Thanks!

EDIT:

This doesn't work:

```
<batchtest>
    <fileset dir="${build}/com/xyzcompany/abcproject/test/junit">
        <include name="**/*.*" />
    </fileset>
</batchtest>
```

It gives me:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CalculatorTest`

Setting it to `<fileset dir="${build}/com/xyzcompany/abcproject/test/junit">` doesn't make any sense since the class doesn't know it is under build. Thus, setting the classpath is the correct option, but doesn't work for `<batchtest>`.

EDIT 2:

Now that I really think about it, it does make sense to do `<fileset dir="${build}/com/xyzcompany/abcproject/test/junit">`. However, when it spins up `java` for `junit` it doesn't run junit from the `${build}` classpath.

EDIT 3:

```
<batchtest>
    <fileset dir="${build}">
        <include name="com/xyzcopmany/abcproject/test/junit/*"/>
    </fileset>
</batchtest>
```

Final answers. Ant should really have better documentation. It is a complex product...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set

```
<fileset dir="com/xyzcompany/abcproject/test/junit">
```

to

```
<batchtest>
    <fileset dir="${buildTests}">
        <include name="**/*Test*.class"/>
    </fileset>
</batchtest>
```

Do not include com/xyzcompany/abcproject/test/junit part in the ${buildTests}.

Comment: Ok, I think you should not include com/xyzcompany/abcproject/test/junit part. Just compile your tests to some directory and include the path to this dir

Comment: Thanks, you were the closest one to help me. People who want the exact answer, see my last edit.

Comment: Could you also please obfuscate your comment (company name and project name) or perhaps delete it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick up the files for your batch test from `${build}` directory, you should tell so

```
    <batchtest>
        <fileset dir="${build}/com/xyzcompany/abcproject/test/junit">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
```